# aws ivs live stream does not work on ios devices (Web)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, live-streaming, amazon-ivs

I use AWS ivs web SDK to capture live streams from the camera of a device and share it with other devices.
among those devices, pc (windows) and Android seem to see the stream just fine, but when I open the stream page on iPhones I can't see it (either in safari or Chrome).

the error i get is :
code:0 , message: Source created failed, type: ErrorNoSource.

might help to know that the stream is secured with an auth token that I get from my server.

does anyone have an idea what to do?

```
const player = await IVSPlayer.create() 
await player.load(streamUrl + '?token=' + token) 
const videoEl = document.getElementById('video-player') 
await player.attachHTMLVideoElement(videoEl) 
await player.play()
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

`player.addEventListener(IVSPlayer.PlayerEventType.ERROR, (err) => console.log(err))`

Instead of `console.log()`, on mobile, you can try to write the error to a `<div>` on the page.

Comment: yes, code:0 , message: Source created failed, type: ErrorNoSource.

Comment: You're calling `load()` before you call `attachHTMLVideoElement()` - can you change this to first attach the video element and then load the playback URL?

Comment: Also - it shouldn't cause an issue, but `IVSPlayer.create()` does not return a promise, so no need to `await` it.